# How to Get live window width and apply it live in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery-1.11.0 in my project. I have a horizontal menu and it looks like sliding menu. my problem was IE support for transition(I applied transition for smooth sliding). My menu works on most of the browser but not works in IE9 and lower. so I decided to do this with Jquery and I got solution for this. When my page loads it works fine (My plan was first i will add `left: calc(-100%+50px);` to my css and then when my Collapse button clicked I will change this css to `left: 0px;`so it will expend and agin when Collapse button clicked it wit restore to `left: calc(-100%+50px);`so it collapsed. But it seems like jquery can not animate`left: calc(-100%+50px);`this type of css. I have tried this with jquery `.animate()` Method. But problem is after expending menu when i go to collapse the menu it don't show any sliding animation. It just add the css to menu.


here is my first try [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/sgguudep/)
here is my second try [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/cseqprcp/1/)
here is my latest try [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/f7j882uk/2/)

Which method is best and what can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another answer. I fixed your javascript. Should work on resize. What I did was resize and reposition the menu on resize. This way the button which is dependent on the menu moves with it. Below is the javascript code.

```
(function($) {
    $(".button").on("click", function() {
        if ($(".menu").css("left") == "0px") {
            $(".menu").stop().animate({
                left: -1 * $(window).width() + 30
            }, 'slow');
        } else {
            $(".menu").stop().animate({
                left: 0
            }, 'slow');
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();

        $(".menu").css("width", width);

        if ($(".menu").css("left") != "0px") {
            $(".menu").css("left", (-1 * $(window).width() + 30));
        }

    });

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the live window width use below code:

`window.innerWidth` gives you the viewport width of the window while
`window.width` gives you the whole window width.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the width of the window you must keep in mind that the user might resize his browser. This is why we wrap our code with the jQuery resize function for a live update of the width. Check the below code:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        // update the width of your element, the below line is just an example on how to do that
        $("#someElementId").css("width", width);
    });
});
```

Comment: @ShohidulAlam this code works on resize, you need to call it on ready aswell outside the resize function.  Call this direct;y after the document ready line : $("#someElementId").css("width", $(window).width());

Comment: @ShohidulAlam I added the missing semicolons and this is a bin showing the code: http://jsbin.com/gituzeneno/1/edit?js,console,output || check out how the box is resized though in the CSS it has a width of 50px.

Comment: Thanks for help ! but my problem is still not finished. Plz See the 3rd jsfiddle and read the texts in jsfiddle.